# Unable to use csv.reader for a non ascii string in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, unicode

This is currently my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import codecs

# original directory
phys_comp_dir = '/Users/lmnt74/Physician_Compare'

# for row in Performance_Scores:
#     print(','.join(row))

# file name
National_Downloadable_File = ('/Physician_Compare_National_Downloadable'
                              '_File.csv')
National_File = csv.reader(open(phys_comp_dir+National_Downloadable_File,
                                newline='', encoding='utf-8'),
                           quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,
                           lineterminator='\n'
                           )

for row in National_File:
    for i in row:
        try:
            print(i)
        except UnicodeError:
            print(i.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lmn74/Physician_Compare/q2.py", line 41, in <module>
    print(i)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xae' in position 52: ordinal not in range(128)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lmnt74/Physician_Compare/q2.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(i.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 52: invalid start byte
```

I am unsure about how to proceed. I know the string that is throwing the error is the (R), the registered trademark. I would like to figure out how to re-write my code so that it is able to check for this in each string OR if a better way exists to allocate for this when reading the file initially, I'm all for that.

What I've done so far:

- I've read the [unicode documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html).
- I've read the [CSV documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/csv.html#csv-fmt-params)
- I've read about the [unicode sandwich](http://johnbachman.net/building-a-python-23-compatible-unicode-sandwich.html)

None of which have helped me or are easy enough reads for me to understand. I'm a fairly new beginner and anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Figured it out, see below:

changed:

```
print(i.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8'))
```

to:

```
print(i.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8', 'ignore'))
```

Sorry to waste anyone's time.

Comment: Are you by chance redirecting the output of your script to another file via the shell redirection `>`?

Comment: @DYZ, at this point, I am just getting it to print the output so I can see it. I will mostly be pushing it into a data frame after I'm done assessing the overall output of the file and cleaning it up.

Comment: Printing non-ASCII correctly depends on the version of Python used and the OS.  A properly configured terminal and the latest Python 3.6 should be able to `print(i)` for any character `i`.  My guess is you are on Linux and your `LANG` environment variable isn't set correctly.

Comment: @MarkTolonen - I'm using a Mac and here is my output after typing in locale into terminal:
    Amits-MBP:~ lmnt74$ locale
    LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
    LC_ALL=

I don't understand why it was giving me so many issues earlier, if UTF-8 is the default.

Comment: That looks correct. What does something simple like  `print('ü')` do?  Also, what Python version are you using?

Comment: It seems that `LC_ALL` is unset. Try setting it to "en_US.UTF-8" as well, maybe that helps...

Comment: @lenz, can you provide documentation to make that fix on a mac? I don't know how to set that variable.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, this is the output I receive, when I go to print that: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xfc' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: I assume it works the same as for any other Unix-based platform, ie. `export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"` – these are just normal environment variables. Put the command in a shell start-up script to make it permanent (eg. in ~/.bashrc if you use bash).